# How to get a class's name from the object?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, methods

I have one function in my script where in the end I'm getting the class object. I want to return a class name from that function. What is the way to get classname from the respective class object?

Comment: What do you mean? From an instance, it's `instance.__class__.__name__`.

Comment: drop into the python prompt, instantiate your object as `instance`, and do `dir(instance)`.

Answer (score 3):

Example:

```
class MyClass:
    def whoami(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__

instance = MyClass()
print instance.whoami()  #<-- prints: MyClass
```

Answer (score 2):

If your have an instance of the class, you can do:

```
return obj.__class__.__name__
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__class__.__name__` in your object;

```
print yourObject.__class__.__name__
```

---

Or this it not object its `class`, your can use this too;

```
class myClass: # Create class
    pass

print myClass.__name__ # It will have 'myClass'
```

---

Regards,